# What version of openssl does .Q.hg require?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to use `.Q.hg` in kdb and I get the following error

```
q).Q.hg`$":https://www.google.com"
'conn. OS reports: Protocol not available
  [0]  .Q.hg`$":https://www.google.com"
       ^
q))
```

When I execute `(-26!)[]` I get the following output:

```
q).Q.hg`$":https://www.google.com"
'conn. OS reports: Protocol not available
  [0]  .Q.hg`$":https://www.google.com"
       ^
q))
```

I have downloaded different versions of openssl from the openssl website and built them from source, but nothing seems to work.

I have also downloaded the certificate as instructed on the kx website and defined the SSL_CA_CERT_FILE variables.

UPDATE: 
output from (-26!)[]:

```
q))(-26!)[]
'Could not initialize openssl. Error was incompatible ssl version

  [4]  (-26!)[]
       ^
q))
```

Output from .z.k:

```
q)).z.K
3.6
q))
```

Distro version:

```
   Static hostname: 
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: 
           Boot ID: 
  Operating System: Linux Mint 19.1
            Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: Could you share your output form -26!? also can I confirm your os?

Comment: It's always good to also include the version and release date information with any query like this about kdb.
`q)(.z.K;.z.k)`

Comment: See the updates that I have added

Answer (score 2):

As per kx [docs](https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/ssl/#suitability-and-restrictions) OpenSSL 1.1 is not supported, you need to use a 1.0.x version